# Как убрать масштабирование при открытой консоли?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иногда при открытии консоли/просмотре верстки у меня масштабируется контент в окне. Настройка зума вверху не помогает, масштабируется даже при большом разрешении окна, но когда закрываю панель с кодом, всё отображается нормально. Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Отключите режим адаптивного просмотра - `Ctrl+Shift+M` при открытой консоли (или вторая иконка слева в верхнем ряду)

Comment: @zhurof большое спасибо))